# How can I convert individual days into one date colum of Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with each day as a column. I would like to convert the dates into a single data column to perform some analysis. I tried searching at many places but none of them talk about this scenario.

```
Product_ID  1/22/2020   1/23/2020   1/24/2020   1/25/2020   1/26/2020   
ABC         1           3           2           3           5   
ABD         2           1           2           2           5   
ABC         0           1           0           3           4   
ABD         1           1           1           3           8   
ABC         3           0           0           3           4   
ABE         6           2           2           1           5
```

The output am looking for is:

```
Date        ABC     ABD     ABE
1/22/2020   4       3       6
1/23/2020   7       2       2
1/24/2020   2       3       2
1/25/2020   9       5       1
1/26/2020   13      13      5
```

It's adding up the data for duplicate columns.

### Edit

Grouping the Product_ID did get me the sum of each product for each date but I still cant extract the dates as a different 'Date' column.

Comment: `df.groupby('Product_ID').sum().T`?

Comment: Thank you Quang. It worked.

Comment: But the column name is still not Date. Actually that product_id column can completely vanish. I need a 'Date' Column name instead. Mean while Am experimenting as well

Comment: See `rename_axis`

Comment: I did. But i still dont see 'date' as a column

df.columns
Index(['ABC', 'ABD', 'ABE'], dtype='object', name='Product_ID')

Comment: Because of the transposition at the end of Quang's operation, `Date` is now the index of your DataFrame. This is probably a good thing. But if you want to have it as a regular column, you can do this: `df['Date'] = df.index`

Comment: Hey Arne:

Thanks for pitching in. 
I tried this fix too. Not i see dates beneath Product_ID and a separate Date column. My goal was to get the date column separately and each of the products as separate columns. So that when i do df.coluns, all i see are ABC, ABD, ABE, Date

Comment: Thanks Arne and Quang for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your initial data frame looks like this:

```
data = {
    'Product_ID': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'ABD', 2: 'ABC', 3: 'ABD', 4: 'ABC', 5: 'ABE'},
    '1/22/2020': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 3, 5: 6},
    '1/23/2020': {0: 3, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 2},
    '1/24/2020': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 2},
    '1/25/2020': {0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 1},
    '1/26/2020': {0: 5, 1: 5, 2: 4, 3: 8, 4: 4, 5: 5}
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
  Product_ID  1/22/2020  1/23/2020  1/24/2020  1/25/2020  1/26/2020
0        ABC          1          3          2          3          5
1        ABD          2          1          2          2          5
2        ABC          0          1          0          3          4
3        ABD          1          1          1          3          8
4        ABC          3          0          0          3          4
5        ABE          6          2          2          1          5
```

you can group your data, as @ Quang Hoang pointed out in comment above. And to get `Date` column, [`.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`.rename()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the old index column to `Date`. If you want, you can also rename column axis. The code is following:

```
df_new = df\
    .groupby('Product_ID').sum().T\
    .reset_index()\
    .rename(columns={'index': 'Date'})\
    .rename_axis(None, axis='columns')

print(df_new)
        Date  ABC  ABD  ABE
0  1/22/2020    4    3    6
1  1/23/2020    4    2    2
2  1/24/2020    2    3    2
3  1/25/2020    9    5    1
4  1/26/2020   13   13    5
```